# Do I must use desired capabilities in Appium and Selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, appium

I have a general question regarding the use of desired capabilities in appium or selenium.
Do I must use desired capabilities in Appium and Selenium?
What happen if I use wrong desired capabilities? Will I get an error of any kind?

Comment: Desired capabilities are critical with Appium.  You cannot create an Appium session without them, at least not that I'm aware of.  Don't worry, though, it's not all that complex.  Once you use it for the basic scenarios like web app, native app, and hybrid, you simply re-use most of the settings for other similar tests.

Answer (score 0):

### DesiredCapabilities

[DesiredCapabilities](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/DesiredCapabilities.html) Class is the set of default supported *desired capabilities* which can be used to create a *desired capabilities object* for requesting remote webdrivers for connecting to selenium server or selenium grid.

### Constructor

The constructors for DesiredCapabilities class are as follows:

- `DesiredCapabilities()`
- `DesiredCapabilities(Capabilities... others)`
- `DesiredCapabilities(Capabilities other)`
- `DesiredCapabilities(java.util.Map<java.lang.String,?> rawMap)`
- `DesiredCapabilities(java.lang.String browser, java.lang.String version, Platform platform)`

### Methods

Some of the commonly used methods from DesiredCapabilities class are as follows:

- `boolean  acceptInsecureCerts()`
- `protected int    amendHashCode()`
- `static DesiredCapabilities   android()`
- `java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object> asMap()`
- `static DesiredCapabilities   chrome()`
- `static DesiredCapabilities   edge()`
- `boolean  equals(java.lang.Object o)`
- `static DesiredCapabilities   firefox()`
- `java.lang.Object getCapability(java.lang.String capabilityName)`
- `Platform getPlatform()`
- `int  hashCode()`
- `static DesiredCapabilities   htmlUnit()`
- `static DesiredCapabilities   internetExplorer()`
- `static DesiredCapabilities   ipad()`
- `static DesiredCapabilities   iphone()`
- `DesiredCapabilities  merge(Capabilities extraCapabilities)`
- `static DesiredCapabilities   operaBlink()`
- `static DesiredCapabilities   safari()`
- `void setAcceptInsecureCerts(boolean acceptInsecureCerts)`
- `void setBrowserName(java.lang.String browserName)`
- `void setJavascriptEnabled(boolean javascriptEnabled)`
- `void setPlatform(Platform platform)`
- `void setVersion(java.lang.String version)`
- `java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object> toJson()`
- `java.lang.String toString()`

For **Selenium** as well as **Appium**, you can use *DesiredCapabilities* class and any of its methods to configure the *WebDriver* instance with the required configuration as per your *Test Specification*

Answer (score 0):

**For Appium**

Wrong desired capabilities means you will get an Http error response from the device.And the test case will fail.

Answer (score 0):

To correctly answer your question, you should understand what is desired capability and why they are used.

**Desired Capabilities** is a way to tell any server (selenium server,appium server) that for automation what kind of **session** we are expecting.

A session may have different configurations as per our requirement.

1. Run tests on mobile device browser
2. Run tests on mobile device app
3. Run tests on desktop different browsers
4. Run tests on desktop browser headless

So to make server understand we tell this information to server using   `DesireCapabilities` class.

*1. Do I must use desired capabilities in Appium and Selenium?*

Yes, it is mandatory to pass desired capabilities in case of Appium and Selenium

*2. What happen if I use wrong desired capabilities?*

If you use wrong desired capabilities, server may throw error or you may get undesired output from server resulting test will not execute or they may giving irrelevant output.

***Undesired output***
*e.g.* you want to run test on chrome browser inside mobile but your tests are running on default browser of mobile device e.g. opera etc

***Server Error***
*e.g.* you want to run test on app inside mobile device but you get error from server that mandatory desired capability `appPackage` and `appActivity` are not passed so server terminates the session.